# How can i print total number of elements in the correct position?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am currently learning Java and am completing exercises based on it; however, there is a specific issue that I am facing with one of the exercises. The task is described below:

> Elements in position
>
> Given a matrix "n x n" containing the numbers a 0 to n2 - 1, return the number of elements that are in the correct position.
>
> For example given a matrix 3x3:
>
> ```
> 4 2 6
> 0 8 5
> 7 1 3
> ```
>
> The correct position of each number is shown in the following matrix:
>
> ```
> 0 1 2
> 3 4 5
> 6 7 8
> ```
>
> The software, having the first matrix as input, should print the value 1, because only 5 is in the correct position.but now i have changed the number of elements in the correct posistion to two it should print two but i get 1 1 im not sure how can i add those 1 and 1 to get two.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        
         int[] arr = {4,2,6,0,8,5,7,1,8};
         
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
          
          int count = 0;
          if (arr[i] == i) {
count++;
System.out.println(+ count);
```

Comment: You are already printing the index. It just so happens that the value of 5 is also at index 5.

Comment: It however seems like the assignment isn't about you printing the index of anything. It's about you printing how many times an arrays value and index are the same value. For that simply declare a variable `int count = 0;` before the loop and increment it with `count++` in your `if (arr[i] == i)` statement. Then print that variable after your loop is done.

Comment: thanks i got very confused,however,now that i have chnaged the number of elements which are in the correct posistion to two i get  1  1 instead of two

Comment: Without seeing this new code of yours I don't know how you expect me to tell you what you did wrong. You should edit your question to show your new code and what error you are getting.

Comment: im not getting any errors its just i dont know how to total up the ones into a single two value

Comment: what should be printed is "TWO" because there are only TWO elements which are in the correct position,but i get 1 1,i want it print it in one line and not show it in ones but add them together thats what i am struggling with

Comment: @user3569752 You declared the count variable **inside** your loop and also print it in the loop. Read my comment above again, i clearly wrote "For that simply declare a variable int count = 0; **before** the loop..." and "Then print that variable **after** your loop is done."

Comment: Move the line `int count = 0;` to before your for loop and `System.out.println(count);` to after your for loop. @user16320675 Well its your fault for both having this userxxx nick. Get a real username, preferable one referencing arachnids in all caps if you want to be cool ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the count variable inside the for loop and also printing the result inside the loop. Here is the correct code to do that -

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        
        int[] arr = {4,2,6,0,8,5,7,1,8};
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
          if (arr[i] == i) {
            count++;
          }
       } 
       System.out.println(count);
   } 
}
```